# Incidence function $\phi: E(G) \rightarrow V(G) \times V(G)$ of union of graphs $G = F \cup H$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Incidence function $\phi: E(G) \rightarrow V(G) \times V(G)$ of union of graphs $G = F \cup H$.

Suppose $F,H$ are graphs. Then according to two books, I've been studying, we can define the $G = F \cup H$ as the union with $V(G) = V(F) \cup V(H)$ and $E(G) = E(F) \cup E(H)$.

However nothing is said about the incidence funcion $\phi$. Is this because it is arbitrary (left unspecified - to be specified by the person performing the operation) or because it is implicit that endpoints of edges in $G$ remains intact ? That is for any edge $e \in E(G)$, the endpoints is respect to $\phi_F$ if $e$ is an edge of $E(F)$ only - the same applies to an  edge of $H$ only.
 But what if $e \in E(F)$ and $e \in E(H)$ ? **How should the endpoints of $e$ in $G$ be specified ?**

Answer (score 1):

If $e$ is a common edge in $F$ and $H$ it should not matter. Since according to the definitions the incidence function of $G$ can also be stated as

$$ \phi ; E(F) \cup E(H) \rightarrow V(F)\cup V(H) \times V(F)\cup V(H)$$

The incidence function remains well-defined for union graphs. If $e$ is a common edge to both $F$ and $H$ it would not matter since $e \in E(F) \cup E(H) $ occurs only once. Now you talk about varying endpoints of an edge. This is impossible. Since an edge is defined **by** the endpoints.I don't know which book you use but say for an example *Deistel*  says an edge is a $2$-subset of $V(G)$ and hence is defined by the endpoints. If $e \in E(F) \cap E(H)$ then the endpoints of $e$, say $v_1$ and $v_2$ are also common to both $V(F)$ and $V(H)$. So the function remains unaffected. Hope I helped.

Comment: An edge is a $2$-subset of $V(G)$ - this is true only for simple graphs ?

Comment: True. I didn't know we were considering multigraphs too. But the rest of the arguments should work. And the function like I said remains well-defined. But not one-to-one anymore.

Comment: But if $e$ is in both $E(F)$ and $E(H)$ - and $\phi_F(e) = \{u,v\}$ and $\phi_H(e) = \{x,y\}$. How can we resolve this matter if $F$ and $H$ are disjoint (no common vertex) ? Should $\phi_G(e) = \{u,v\}$ or should $\phi_G(e) = \{x,y\}$ ??

Comment: If $F$ and $H$ are disjoint, how can they have a common edge?? If they have no common vertex they surely have no common edge.

Comment: As I understand graph theory a graph $G=(V,E)$ is an ordered pair consisting of a vertex set and a edge set. Suppose the edges are $E=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (the first five natural numbers). Then surely another graph $F$ (disjoint from $G$) can have the same edge set, but no vertices in common with $G$. The only thing that matters is the incidence function $\phi$ which map an edge to a pair of vertices - Indeed $\phi_G$ and $\phi_F$ differs, since the co-domain is completely different.

Comment: @Nicolas Lykke Iversen: No that is not true. A graph is not an arbitrary ordered pair of sets $V$ and $E$. No the edge set is defined on the vertex set. I've worked mostly on simple graphs but the definition is pretty much the same for multigraphs. <br>  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph <br> The edges are defined by their endpoints. So $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ is an edge set iff $1 = \{ a, b\}$ for $a, b \in V(G)$ and so on..

Comment: Thank you. But it this the same as the definition in my book (I will list it exactly as it stands):
A graph $G$ is  an ordered pair $(V(G), E(G))$ consisting of a set $V(G)$ of vertices and a set $E(G)$ of edges, toghether with an incidence function $\phi_g$ that associates with each edge of $G$ an unordered pair of (not neccesarily distict) vertices of $G$. This is the definition in my book from Springer. This says nothing that $1 = \{a,b\}$ for $a,b \in V(G)$. It says that $\phi_G(1) = \{a,b\}$ for $a,b \in V(G)$. This is not the same thing ?